# Impersonal "sich" in "um .. zu" construction?

Tags: grammar, infinitive, reflexive

From  *Spiegel Magazine*:

> Das ist eine Vermutung, nicht unbegründet, aber eben eine Vermutung. Um **sich** der Wahrheit weiter anzunähern, wird es auf die Ermittler ankommen.

Am I correct in understanding that **sich** here is impersonal, i.e., does not refer to anyone in particular? Is it similar to something like the following?

> Es ist nicht einfach, **sich** so etwas vorzustellen.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: This sentence is at most borderline grammatical. I am not sure why, but somehow I refuse to read *sich* as impersonal in this sentence; since it obviously has to be read that way to make sense, the sentence is not grammatical for me.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this sentence as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, *sich* in both of your examples is impersonal. And yes, both sentences of yours are entirely analogous, because both use infinitive constructions.

Infinitives can be connected to a person or not. Depending on whether they are or not, a *sich* can be replaced by another reflexive pronoun. Compare:

> Es ist nicht so einfach, *sich* so etwas vorzustellen.
>   Es ist *für mich* nicht einfach, *mir* so etwas vorzustellen.
>   Es ist *für Juliane* nicht einfach, *sich* so etwas vorzustellen.

Only in the first sentence is *sich* truly impersonal. The others relate *mir* and *sich* to the person in the first part of themselves. In the line from the Spiegel, everybody and nobody are coming closer to the truth, so no *particular* person is meant, hence impersonal.

Answer (score 2):

"Sich" is a reflexive.

Reflexive verbs use the reflexive pronouns with the meaning “oneself” ("sich selbst").

For example:

Ich dusche **mich.**

But if we have also an accusative object then we have to use the reflexive pronoun in the dative.

For example:

Ich putze **mir** die Zähne

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. "annähern" IS a reflexive verb, cf. http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/annaehern. This is ungrammatical: "Der Ermittler nähert der Wahrheit an." - correct: "Der Ermittler nähert SICH der Wahrheit an."

Comment: Yes, of course *sich* is reflexive in the example, but the question was whether it is impersonal. I am not sure if this is normal grammar terminology, but I understand 'impersonal' in this context to mean that *sich* doesn't actually refer to anyone - just like *sich* in the infinitive *sich annähern*, and unlike *sich* in *er nähert sich an*.